# dictionary in appdelegate access in all classes ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I have a static dictionary placed in app delegate that all classes can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use NSUserDefaults, as you can access them fraom everywhere in your application.

You set the value as a regular dictionary, the only difference is that you should force-save them:

```
defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
[defaults synchronize];//FORCESAVE
```

You access them also in a dictionary manner:

```
[defaults objectForKey:@"someKey"]; //will give you someValue
```

Comment: TompaLompa is correct, NSUserDefaults is the way to go for this kind of storage.  BTW you can store an NSDictionary in NSUserDefaults as well as NSStrings, NSArrays, etc).  It would be [defaults setObject:someDictionary forKey:@"myDictionary"];